# Combinations of a list of list - Elementwise

Tags: python, list, combinations

I am looking for a method to generate all possible combinations of a list of lists, under the condition that there should only be "elementwise" combinations. Thus, if we have the lists [1,2] and [3,4], then the outcome [3,2] is allowed, but [4,2] is not allowed. With itertools.product(*lists) the last outcome is included.

Thus, I want the following output: [1,2], [3,2], [1,4], [3,4], and the following options should be 'skipped': [4,2], [1,3]. Note that the order is important! Thus I do not allow [2,3], just [3,2].

I know that I can check for this afterwards, but since I am generating many many lists in my code, I rather avoid this.

Comment: I don't understand why you would allow [2,3] and not [3,2]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the two lists in one list of lists and then after transposing the container list, use `itertools.product()` on it.

```
import itertools
original_list =  [[1,2], [3,4]]
transposed_list = list(map(list, zip(*original_list)))
print(list(itertools.product(*transposed_list)))
```

Outputs:
`[(1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 2), (3, 4)]`

**EDIT | Explaining how the list was transposed:**

By definition, transposing is the process of exchanging places.

`*original_list` means `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`. The asterisk refers to the elements of the list, rather than the list as a whole

`zip` basically pairs values together 'element-wise':
e.g. with our `original_list` we have `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`. Calling zip on our elements will result in `(1,3)` and `(2,4)`. The values were paired element-wise.
Note that the resulting pairs are not in list form.

`map` applies a function to every element in an input list. In our example,
we want to apply the (built-in) `list` function to our element-wise pairs - i.e. convert each tuple of pairs into a list. This is what turns  `(1,3)` and `(2,4)` into `[1,3]` and `[2,4]`

Finally, convert our result from the mapping into a containing list, holding our element-wise pairs, producing `[ [1,3], [2,4] ]`

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly doing what I want! Can you explain to me what the third line exactly does? I tried to google it, but couldn't find a clear explanation.

Comment: @StudentNL See updated answer, hope clears things up.